# How many arrangements of the letters in "DISAPPEARANCES" have all of the following properties?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

i)there are at least two letters between each A.
ii) ends with an A, and
iii) the consonants are not in alphabetical order.

The answers is C(3+(11-4)-1,(11-4)) C(11,8)(8!/2!2!-1) (3!/2!1!). 
Why is it the answer?

Comment: here is a MathJax tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
you might edit the answer in a more mathematical way.
and what did you try

Answer (score 3):

Going through the factors one by one,

- $C(3+(11-4)-1,(11-4)) = \binom{3+(11-4)-1}{11-4}$ is the number of ways to choose the positions of the A's.
- $C(11,8) = \binom{11}{8}$ is the number of ways to choose which of the remaining positions are filled by consonants (and which by the vowels I,E,E).
- $\frac{8!}{2!2!}-1$ counts the number of ways to rearrange the consonants D,S,P,P,R,N,C,S, taking account that there are two identical P's and two identical S's, and subtracting one to rule out the order C,D,N,P,P,R,S,S.
- $\frac{3!}{2!1!}$ counts the number of ways to rearrange the vowels I,E,E.

The first step is the trickiest. (I initially suggested the stars and bars method here, but I think it's simpler to do directly.

We can think of a successful outcome of this step as a sequence of A's and question marks: something like `???A???A?????A`. The last letter must be A and every A must have two non-A letters (two question marks) after it, so all such sequences are permutations of two `A??` blocks, seven `?`'s, and an `A` at the end.

So there are $9$ things we rearrange, and $\binom{9}{7} = \binom{3+(11-4)-1}{11-4}$ ways to pick out which of them are `?`s and which of them are `A??` blocks.

Comment: Can you show how you found the answer of the first step by the stars and bars method? I'm unable to get it by myself

Comment: @user46208 I've edited my answer.